# Syntax error on closing brace in puppet class

Tags: puppet

I must be losing it.  This class gives an error stating '`Syntax error at '}'` on the last line of the file when running `puppet agent`.  Am I missing a brace or other obvious issue?

```
class roles::webserver::na {

  class { 'profiles::webserver::ourwebserver':
     market => 'na'
  }

  Class['profiles::webserver::ourwebserver']

}
```

..not sure if it helps diagnose, but `ourwebserver` starts out like so:

```
class profiles::webserver::ourwebserver($market) {
```

...

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the problem was with the `Class['profiles::webserver::ourwebserver']` bit, apparently with only one class the ordering statement above isn't needed.

Comment: What ordering statement?  `Class['profiles::webserver::ourwebserver']` is just a class reference.  It is indeed out of place by itself.